How to set a Minecraft Villager entity's pathing to a Location? i.e. make mob walk to specific spot, using Spigot API
For Minecraft, utilizing the Spigot API, I have a LivingEntity Villager that I would like to path, or "walk" to a Location.
I have seen some older examples using PathEntity to perform this effect, to varying degrees of success, but such methods now appear to have been removed from more modern versions of the Spigot API.
I am currently using the spigot-api-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded & craftbukkit-1.21.1 jar libraries in my build path, so I would like to find a solution that works with v1.21.1 or higher. Thank you.

maybe the game-development-stack would a better place for your question - try to post your question there

@MartinFrank Thank you for the tip, I will give it a shot.

looks good :-D https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/212344/how-to-make-a-minecraft-villager-walk-to-a-location

The easiest way would be to use paper spigot. It got way more optimizations than normal spigot and you can access the pathfinder of every mob easily.
 Villager entity = // your entity
 Location location = // your location
 entity.getPathfinder().moveTo(location);

https://jd.papermc.io/paper/1.21.1/com/destroystokyo/paper/entity/Pathfinder.html
